# ImportError for jsonrpc

Tags: python, json, json-rpc

I am trying to follow [this](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/python-json-rpc) walkthrough on how to use the `ServiceProxy` in `jsonrpc`.

I followed the directions but I am getting an error no the import of the `ServiceProxy`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import sys
import json
from jsonrpc import ServiceProxy

givex = jsonrpc.ServiceProxy()
print "foo"
```

which is resulting in:

[image]

Would anyone be able to help me out with some ideas on how to fix this, or have  a suggestion for a better jsonrpc library to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutoral you are following seems to be outdated. Try

```
from jsonrpc.proxy import JSONRPCProxy
givex = JSONRPCProxy.from_url("http://localhost/url/of/your/service.py")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run this under Python 3.x, bear in mind that it is not yet supported. Many JSON RPC libraries have very similar names, but this particular one (jsonrpc without the dash, different from json-rpc or jsonrpc2) does not support Python 3 as of december 2016.

Here is the link for this particular library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonrpc